# Firefox на Ubuntu. Крестик (кнопка закрыть) отдалена от угла экрана. Можно ли её пододвинуть?

Tags: ubuntu, интерфейс, firefox, расширения, gnome

Может, есть какое-нибудь расширение для этого? Я не нашёл. У крестика, между прочим, круглый хотспот, то есть простое перемещение не поможет. Мне нужно, чтобы можно было быстро отвести курсор вправо-вверх и одним кликом закрыть окно, но это невозможно с такой кнопкой. Версия Firefox - "103.0.2 (64 бита)". Проверив подсвечиваемую кнопку "закрыть", можно выяснить, что хотспот у кнопки вообще круглый. То есть, просто пододвинуть кнопку вправо-вверх не поможет, в углу всё ещё будет пустое место. [image: Круглый крестик]

Скорее всего, виноват gnome.

Comment: Не помешает скриншот, как это выглядит? И напишите в вопросе вашу версию Firefox, нажав на [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1441214/edit).

Comment: У меня тоже кнопка круглая, но это не мешает ее нажимать в самом углу экрана. У меня не gnome, но возможно вам надо покопаться в настройках Window Manager, попробовать задать разные обрамления для окон или уменьшить ширину рамки.

Comment: @Vadik Круглая - это я про хотспот. По законам геометрии, круг не поместится в угол пиксел-в-пиксел, так что у вас она работает как квадратная. Спасибо, попробую. Наверно, легко решается, да времени все не нахожу.